# deal when several extended matchers with same name

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using custom matchers from two external libraries [jest-dom/extend-expect](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom) and [jest-extended](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended). Both libraries defines a matcher named `toBeEmpty`, but with different behaviour. One expects a string/array/object/iterable to be empty, the other expects a DOM element to be empty.

My feeling is that the order in jest configuration impacts which matcher is actually used in test:

```
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect',
        'jest-extended',
    ],
```

```
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        'jest-extended',
        '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect',
    ],
```

With first config, `jest-extended` version takes precedence, while with the second one, the `jest-dom` version wins. Is this correct?

Is there a way to use both matchers? Should it be the library author to detect that another matcher already exists and deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expect.extend` merges matchers into matcher object, matchers with same names are being replaced without a notice, this is [a known problem](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6243).

A way to prevent name collisions is to provide namespaces for matchers and set them in Jest setup file specified in `setupFilesAfterEnv`. Matcher functions can be imported directly from matcher libraries and supplied to `expect.extend`.

`@testing-library/jest-dom` provides public entry point to import matchers:

```
const domMatchers = require('@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers');
const namespacedDomMatchers = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(domMatchers).map(([name, matcher]) => [`dom_${name}`, matcher])
);

expect.extend(namespacedDomMatchers);
```

`jest-extended` has internal module that can be imported as well:

```
const extendedMatchers = require('jest-extended/dist/matchers');
const namespacedExtendedMatchers = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(extendedMatchers).map(([name, matcher]) => [`extended_${name}`, matcher])
);

expect.extend(namespacedExtendedMatchers);
```

Matchers from both libraries become available as `dom_toBeEmpty` and `extended_toBeEmpty`.

Comment: thank you so much for the clear and detailed response. Renaming the matchers is an interesting option